# Multiple AND condition within IF clause in xslt

Tags: xslt

I am trying to multiple AND condition within If cause in XSLT and it is not working. Below is the code snippet I am trying to write.
Code Snippet :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp dpconfig">
   <xsl:output method="xml" />
   <xsl:variable name="vAccStatus" select="dp:http-request-header('AccStatus')" />
   <xsl:variable name="vRules" select="dp:http-request-header('Rules')" />
   <xsl:variable name="vAccess" select="dp:http-request-header('Access')" />
   <xsl:variable name="vOut" select="dp:http-request-header('Out')" />
   <xsl:variable name="vUserAccess" select="dp:http-request-header('UserAccess')" />
   <xsl:variable name="vLevel" select="dp:http-request-header('Level')" />
   <xsl:variable name="vPerformed" select="dp:http-request-header('Performed')" />
   <xsl:variable name="vParticipation" select="dp:http-request-header('Participation')" />
   <xsl:variable name="vPoints" select="dp:http-request-header('Points')" />
   <xsl:template match="/">      
      <xsl:variable name="res">
         <NS1:AuthResponse xmlns:NS1="http://test.com/test">
            <NS1:AuthDetails>
               <NS1:Detail>
                  <NS1:AuthCheckType>FunctionsPerformed</NS1:AuthCheckType>
                  <NS1:Result>NOT_PERFORMED</NS1:Result>
                  <NS1:ErrorCode />
                  <NS1:AuthDetails />
               </NS1:Detail>
               <NS1:Detail>
                  <NS1:AuthCheckType>ServiceParticipation</NS1:AuthCheckType>
                  <NS1:Result>NOT_PERFORMED</NS1:Result>
                  <NS1:ErrorCode />
                  <NS1:AuthDetails />
               </NS1:Detail>              
            </NS1:AuthDetails>
            <NS1:Access>GRANT_ACCESS</NS1:Access>
            <NS1:ErrorCode>0</NS1:ErrorCode>
         </NS1:AuthResponse>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test="(($vAccStatus = 'N') and ($vRules = 'N') and ($vAccess = 'N') and ($vOut = 'N') and ($vUserAccess = 'N') and ($vLevel = 'N') and ($vPerformed = 'N') and ($vParticipation = 'N') and ($vPoints = 'N'))">
         <xsl:copy-of select="$res"/>
      </xsl:if>      
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can you please let me know what is the issue here and how to make it work

Comment: So which error do you get from which tool exactly? Or how else does it fail when "it is not working"?

Comment: basically i am not getting any error but it is not executing the statements within the IF clause even if the conditions are satisfying.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown us. To find your bug, we therefore need to see the things you haven't shown us. Incidentally, all the parentheses in your expression are redundant.

Comment: I was trying to copy one XML file if the condition satisfy . But in this case its not able to copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it is not executing the statements within the IF clause even if the
> conditions are satisfying.

I believe you are mistaken about this. If the instructions contained in your `xsl:if` statement are not executed, it is because the test returns false. You can verify this by running the following stylesheet and adding the result to your question:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" 
extension-element-prefixes="dp">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="vAccStatus" select="dp:http-request-header('AccStatus')" />
<xsl:variable name="vRules" select="dp:http-request-header('Rules')" />
<xsl:variable name="vAccess" select="dp:http-request-header('Access')" />
<xsl:variable name="vOut" select="dp:http-request-header('Out')" />
<xsl:variable name="vUserAccess" select="dp:http-request-header('UserAccess')" />
<xsl:variable name="vLevel" select="dp:http-request-header('Level')" />
<xsl:variable name="vPerformed" select="dp:http-request-header('Performed')" />
<xsl:variable name="vParticipation" select="dp:http-request-header('Participation')" />
<xsl:variable name="vPoints" select="dp:http-request-header('Points')" />
   
<xsl:template match="/">
    <variables>
        <vAccStatus>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vAccStatus"/>
        </vAccStatus>
        <vRules>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vRules"/>
        </vRules>
        <vAccess>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vAccess"/>
        </vAccess>
        <vOut>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vOut"/>
        </vOut>
        <vUserAccess>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vUserAccess"/>
        </vUserAccess>
        <vLevel>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vLevel"/>
        </vLevel>
        <vPerformed>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vPerformed"/>
        </vPerformed>
        <vParticipation>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vParticipation"/>
        </vParticipation>
        <vPoints>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vPoints"/>
        </vPoints>
    </variables>
</xsl:template>
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried by passing  all values to N still it is not executing within IF condition.

Comment: Then there must be something you're not telling us, because the problem cannot be reproduced from your description. There is nothing wrong with your test (other than the redundant parentheses) - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFK9z

Comment: Yes you are correct this condition is working fine there were issue in the values which we are putting in condition .